# Null check operator used on a null value - StaggeredGridView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, staggered-gridview

I'm working on a **'Notes'** app.

So far, it has a **`HomeScreen()`** and **`Note()`** widget. The first is the screen where the notes are to be displayed and the second is a custom widget which is inflated by the way the notes are going to be displayed. I'm using **`Card()`** to display each note.

To dynamically set the sizes of the Cards, I'm using `StaggeredGridView`.

Here's my code.. **`notesList`** is the array of notes.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';

import '../models/notes_list.dart';
import '../services/notes_service.dart';
import '../note.dart';
import './add_note_screen.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  NotesService get service => GetIt.I<NotesService>();
  List<NotesList> notesList = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    notesList = service.getNotes();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: notesList.length == 0
          ? AppBar(title: Text('Create a Note'))
          : AppBar(title: Text('Safe')),
      body: StaggeredGridView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        itemCount: notesList.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverStaggeredGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2,
          staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
        ),
        itemBuilder: (_, index) => Note(
          notesList[index].noteTitle,
          notesList[index].noteContent,
          notesList[index].noteDateTime,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => AddNoteScreen())),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.endFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

I want to display only 2 notes across the screen and with the help of above code, I'm able to achieve that.

One problem I was already facing was that the **`StaggeredGridView`** was scrolling infinitely. My actual work today was to solve this issue. However, I stumbled upon a new issue and that's

> Null check operator used on a null value

My debug console points to the StaggeredGridView as the source of this error. I'm trying to find a solution, only I couldn't.

Here's the error stack trace.

```
The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/src/rendering/sliver_variable_size_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 365 pos 12: 'child != null': is not true.

The relevant error-causing widget was
SliverStaggeredGrid
..\…\widgets\staggered_grid_view.dart:506
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#2      RenderSliverVariableSizeBoxAdaptor.paintExtentOf
package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/…/rendering/sliver_variable_size_box_adaptor.dart:365
#3      RenderSliverStaggeredGrid.performLayout
package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/…/rendering/sliver_staggered_grid.dart:317
#4      RenderObject.layout
package:flutter/…/rendering/object.dart:1777
#5      RenderSliverEdgeInsetsPadding.performLayout
package:flutter/…/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:132
#6      RenderSliverPadding.performLayout
package:flutter/…/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:371
```

Comment: Provide the error stacktrace please

Comment: Extremely Sorry. Updated my question with the error stack trace.

Comment: I mean fully full stack trace, cause it looks like there is some logic error in your implementation. And the full code of widget with that `StaggeredGridView` would be very helpful too

Comment: Please check if I need to add more details.

Comment: try add `shrinkWrap : true`

Comment: Thanks for details, hope I'll help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've discovered `StaggeredGridView.builder` throws that error when it's not enough items to cover the screen, if you use `shrinkWrap: true` you'll have to provide bounded height, which is not a universal solution,

**but** according to your expectations, `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder` is more appropriate to use in your situation.

So, I've used `StaggeredGridView.countBuilder`, it requires all necessary parameters and it works for me with your `HomeScreen` code:

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
    itemCount: notesList.length,
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    staggeredTileBuilder: (index) => StaggeredTile.fit(1),
    itemBuilder: (_, index) => Note(
      notesList[index].noteTitle,
      notesList[index].noteContent,
      notesList[index].noteDateTime,
    ),
  )
```

Comment: It solved both the issues at hand. Thanks. But I still need to figure out what was the cause of that error.